How to check, the metadat of a WHL file (python library package) in order to know what it wants for : platform, interpreter and version
I know, you'd ask why I would want to this, so I have a WHL file to install on windows with a title like :
nameAndVersion-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
Sadly, it does not install the result is :
Error "filename.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform"
Yes I am running python 3.8 (3.8.10) on windows 10, 64bits(x86 not arm).
I also checked that I was running CPython using the platform module in the interpreter.
At this point I am questioning whether the WHL file specifies it's requirements correctly.
I know they're just zip files, I looked into it but I do not know where is the data that allows pip to detect I am on the "wrong" platform ?
This is very weird because the same wheel installed on other windows 10 PCs running the exact same version of Python.
Could the root of the issue be how much newer the version of windows 10 is related to the WHL file ?

cp38-win_amd64 is a wheel for Python 3.8, Windows, on Intel/AMD 64 bit. "Yes I am running python 3.8 (3.8.10) on windows 10, 64bits" Ok, your windows is 64bits, but what about Python? It's possible to install 32-bit Python on 64-bit windows but that Python wouldn't install 64-bit wheels. Check: python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"

Thanks, this was the issue, misc clicked the wrong download (:
